# convert all specified symbol to another in all html tags except textfields and textareas with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want convert all Latin digits to Arabic digits  in all html element except textfields,textarea tags with jquery.

```
arabic digits=('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹');
latin digits=('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
```

I know regex is solution for converting all arabic to digits,but my struggle is convert only text that are in specified html tags.

Comment: yes,exactly what I want is convert everything except input types, like textareas,text fields and .... .everything expect inputs and text areas

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry , I update question, your answer seems good,please write down again with  updated question requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on the question, it sounds like you *don't* want just `div`, `span`, and `p` elements, but all elements that aren't form fields.

You can loop through all non-form-field elements on the page using:

```
$("*:not(textarea, input, select)").each(function() {
    // ...do something here...
});
```

Within the function, you can update *just* the text of the element (not any text in its descendant elements) using `.contents()` (which gets all child nodes, including text nodes) with `.filter` (to filter out everything but text nodes) and `.each` (to loop through the remaining children); then update `this.nodeValue` to update the text node's text:

```
$("*:not(textarea, input, select)").each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // 3 = text node
    }).each(function() {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/*...your regex replacement here...*/);
    });
});
```

---

You seemed to say you knew how to do the replacement with regex, but below you suggest you don't. Here's one fairly simple way:

Once, up front:

```
var arabicToLatinMap = {
    "۰": "0",
    "۱": "1",
    "۲": "2",
    "۳": "3",
    "۴": "4",
    "۵": "5",
    "۶": "6",
    "۷": "7",
    "۸": "8",
    "۹": "9"
};
var arabicRegEx = /[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g;
```

Then in the relevant place:

```
this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(arabicRegEx, function(digit) {
    return arabicToLatinMap[digit];
});
```

---

Side note: 0, 1, 2, 3 and such aren't *latin* digits. Interestingly, they're *Arabic* digits, it's just that they're *western* Arabic rather than the *eastern* Arabic digits now in use in the middle east. So this is really a eastern-to-western Arabic digit converter. :-) The western world got their digits from the extraordinary mathematicians of the Arabic world circa the 9th-10th centuries.

Comment: would you please add regex statement?

Comment: You said you *had* the regex, so I didn't bother to think about it. Re the `this.nodeType === 3`, see the comment next to it and the explanation in the text.

Comment: I said I know the solution is with regex,Thank you very much. I check it.

Comment: @zhilevan: Yeah, I realized that later. I've updated with a better regex solution than my first. Best,